# How to access a specific policy in Windows without using the graphical interface?

Tags: windows, powershell, security, gpo, domaincontroller

### What I Have

The "path" of a specific policy like the following

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account
Policies\Password Policy\Enforce password history
```

I can navigate the tree into the Group Policy Mgt tool and with the previous path reach the desired policy.

### What I want

Reach the same result from Powershell or other scripting language.

**Ideal** is a function that takes as `input` the previous path and returns as `output` the value (or notDefined) for the specific policy.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: I would check out [Get-GPOReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gporeport?view=win10-ps). I would consider this a script writing request rather than troubleshooting an issue. It would be best if you attempted to code the solution yourself and post here the specific areas that cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Many GPO Policies can easily retrieved in the registry, especially those from Administrative Templates (have a look in the .admx files in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions).
However, some Windows Settings are more tricky to discover, as the one you want to get.
The full PowerShell version will be :

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\ -Name F).F[82]
```

However, I strongly recommend you to not modify registry security (if you don't, you can't get this property this way).

To avoid this, you can use a mix between cmd and PowerShell :

```
(net accounts | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':' | 
    Where P1 -eq 'Length of password history maintained').P2
```

or more readeable :

```
(net accounts | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':' -PropertyNames Property, Value | 
    Where Property -eq 'Length of password history maintained').Value
```

As you can see in the first way, when you have the registry value, it is easy to get mostly all of the policies (without modifying security) :

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path <Some path> -Name <Some Value>
```

If you want only the value :

```
 Get-ItemProperty -Path <Some path> -Name <Some Value> | Select -ExpandProperty <Some Value>
```

or

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path <Some path> -Name <Some Value>).<Some Value>
```

Add some explanations, this is a part of FileSys.admx (as an example, there are many other .admx files) :

```
   <policy name="DisableCompression" class="Machine" 
    displayName="$(string.DisableCompression)" 
    explainText="$(string.DisableCompressionText)" 
    presentation="$(presentation.CompressionOptions)" 
    key="System\CurrentControlSet\Policies" 
    valueName="NtfsDisableCompression">
      <parentCategory ref="NTFS" />
      <supportedOn ref="windows:SUPPORTED_Windows7" />
      <enabledValue>
        <decimal value="1" />
      </enabledValue>
      <disabledValue>
        <decimal value="0" />
      </disabledValue>
    </policy>
```

`valueName="NtfsDisableCompression"` is for the registry value

`class="Machine"` is for HKLM (User for HKCU)

`key="System\CurrentControlSet\Policies"` is for the path in the machine or user registry

So, you can read it with

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies\ `
                  -Name NtfsDisableCompression).NtfsDisableCompression
```

An error will be flushed if the policy is not configured

```
try
{
   (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies\ `
                     -Name NtfsDisableCompression -ErrorAction Stop).NtfsDisableCompression
}
catch
{
   "Policy not configured"
}
```

If the parameter you want to check is outside the scope of a GPO or is defined manually, if you need to know the value to request, it will be the same syntax, except the `-Path` parameter will not contains a `Policies` key. Here an example for checking if a proxy is enabled :

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name ProxyEnable
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciated your answer. I am going to try. I am new to windows and to the concept of polices. An other way I was exploring is wrapping the XML report from `Gpo-Report` into an object in powershell and cascading through the xml fields. I am going to explore your suggestion. I really appreciated your kind help.

Comment: The GPO reports are fine if you want to know what policies are applied, I probably misunderstood your question, since I thought you want to check specific policies. In this case, registry seems a better way

Comment: No I misunderstood the GPO Report :( I thought it was going to give me a snapshot of the state of all the proxies, showing also the not applied with something like `Not defined` but I was too optimistic. But can I assume that the ones not in the report are not defined? Sorry if this sounds stupid, but maybe I haven't really grasped the concept of proxies. Thanks for your time btw, Laura

Comment: GPO report can show you this only if proxies are defined by GPO, See my edit anwser